# regex matching in mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have a mod_rewrite rule as follows:

```
RewriteRule tshirt[s]*$ /thsirt.php
```

The idea being that `myurl.com/tshirt` and `myurl.com/tshirts` should both redirect to `tshirt.php`.

`myurl.com/tshirt` redirects as expected, but `myurl.com/tshirts` 404s. I've tried clearing the cache, trying with different browsers on different computers, same behavior. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Ignoring the typo in your example, this works as expected. /tshirt, /tshirts, /tshirtssss all rewrite to `thsirt.php`.

Comment: That typo was, in fact, the problem. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```
RewriteRule tshirt(s?)*$ /thsirt.php
```